# Which version of Spring I should start learning?

Tags: spring

From which version I should start learning Spring framework?

I am confused from which version I should start, there are multiple major versions strating from 2 till 5.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for code specific questions.

Comment: but still if someone could help that will be great,As Spring framework is also all about code...

Answer (score 1):

Start with latest version is a general rule of thumb. Unless you are working in an environment (say collaborative project) where you have no choice but to use a specific version.

Docs will have sections explaining concepts for a newbie.

In a framework like Spring major versions have different concepts about how things should be handled and things wouldn't be compatible between versions. Why learn something which is known to be outdated and not supported by newer version.

Newer version also introduce newer technologies and paradigms e.g. Spring 4 introduced websockets and Sprint 5 has support for reactive style and HTTP2.

Also newer version would be fixing what is broken in a previous version.